# Spring wiring NullPointerException in JUnit test class

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, junit

I have written a JUnit class for my Bean `Task`. The first test, `testTaskShouldNotBeNull`, passes OK. However the second one, `testTaskTitle`, throws a NullPointerException. The `title` field is being set in the JavaConfig for my bean so I am unsure why it is null.

My `Task` bean:

```
package com.webapps.ToDoList;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class Task {

    private String title;

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
}
```

My JavaConfig:

```
package com.webapps.ToDoList;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class TaskConfig {

    @Bean
    public Task task() {
        Task task = new Task();
        task.setTitle("A Generic Title!");
        return task;
    }
}
```

And my JUnit test class:

```
package com.webapps.ToDoList;

import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import junit.framework.TestCase;

@ContextConfiguration(classes = TaskConfig.class)
public class TaskTest extends TestCase {

    private Task task;

    public void testTaskShouldNotBeNull() {
        assertNull(task);
    }

    public void testTaskTitle() {
        assertNull(task.getTitle());
    }
}
```

Update:

I have tried adding the `@Autowired` annotation to the `Task` variable in the test class, which made no difference.

Perhaps my file structure is causing an issue?

[image]

After adding `@Test` and `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` annotations I am getting the following result:

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError
at junit.framework.Assert.fail(Assert.java:55)
at junit.framework.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:22)
at junit.framework.Assert.assertNotNull(Assert.java:256)
at junit.framework.Assert.assertNotNull(Assert.java:248)
at junit.framework.TestCase.assertNotNull(TestCase.java:417)
at com.webapps.ToDoList.TaskTest.testTaskShouldNotBeNull(TaskTest.java:26)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:176)
at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:141)
at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:122)
at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:142)
at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:125)
at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:129)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:252)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:247)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.junit3.JUnit3TestReference.run(JUnit3TestReference.java:121)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Comment: Without a `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` the `@ContextConfiguration` annotation is pretty much useless and you need `@Autowired` on the `task` field.

Comment: you need @Autowired before private Task task;?

Comment: Test shouldnotbe null and assertnull does not fit in my opinion should be assertnotnull

Comment: @Jens Right, I got them mixed up. Using `assertNotNull` I can confirm my first test fails with `AssertionFailedError`.
@M.Deinum I have added this now but it still does not seem to find my `Task` bean.
@user7294900 Is that a guess? I added it but still no luck.

Comment: As mentioned you need `@Autowired` on the `task` field.

Comment: Use a Debugger and check what is happend, is your configuration called or not for instance. Maybe the component scan doesn't fit, so the configuration is not found

Comment: From what I can tell the configuration is not being called. Being new to Spring I am unsure why - do you have any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complete test class without imports should look as follows (with Spring 4.3.9.RELEASE and Junit 4.12)

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TaskConfig.class)
public class TaskTest extends TestCase {

    @Autowired
    private Task task;

    @Test
    public void testTaskShouldNotBeNull() {
        assertNotNull(task);
    }

    @Test
    public void testTaskTitle() {
        assertNotNull(task.getTitle());
    }
}
```

Essentially all points have been already made in the comments though, except for the missing @Test annotations

Comment: Thanks I'll try the `@Test` annotations when I'm back at my PC - do these indicate that the context specified by `@ContextConfiguration` is to be used for that method?

Comment: It's the JUnit annotation indicating that the particular method is a test. It is not related to Spring, you should also use it when you create basic unit tests for any plain non-Spring application in order JUnit to be able to process them.

Comment: It is a failed assertion. Did you also change it to assertNotNull, as someone remarked in the comments? Btw. the code in my answer should execute without errors as it is, unless you changed the classes being tested, so you might as well try to copy-paste it.

Comment: Thanks I have done that now. Strangely the `testTaskShouldNotBeNull()` test passes when I right-click on that method and run it, but fails when I run the whole test class...

Comment: Put a breakpoint into the @Bean creation method in TaskConfig and check whether it stops when executing one test / the entire testclass

Comment: Yeah it hits the config only when running a single test.

Comment: That should not happen. Possibly some issue with your local environment. Does your project contain any other classes, dependencies etc. beside the ones affected with this test? If yes, then you might try to create a brand new project containing only these and check whether the problem occurs in there as well.

Comment: I just deleted the existing run configurations and created a new one to run all test methods, and it now works fine! Thanks very much for your previous help :-)